# Matlab loop statement is driving me mad

Tags: matlab

Can someone please help me out with this loop over here? Matlab simple refuses to consider the for o=k:k-20 statement inside the if statement. :pullingmyhair:

```
if d(k)<=-1.5 || d(k) >=1.5
    k
    tab=tab+1
    6

    for o=k:k-20  
        5
        if abs(d(o))<abs(d(o-1))
        bench_value=o;
        break;
        end
    end
.
.
.
.
.
end
```

Comment: Wrong site. Try stackoverflow?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would better fit on StackOverflow (but I didn't migrate because it's answered already).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looping from k to k-20 by +1 steps. Try with o = k:-1:-20.